# Map <C-i> and <Tab> independently

Tags: vim

I know vim has a wickness related to the 7-bit ASCII encoding but the real bad thing is I can't map any of these chars with Vim + Mintty:

```
" ^ <C-'> <C-1> <C-2> <C-3> <C-4> <C-5> <C-6> <C-7> <C-8> 
<C-9> <C-0> <C-i> <C-Tab> <C-S-Tab> ...
```

I also know that  and  are seens as the same char on vim but I found there is a workaround using the `set` keyword. For example I was able to map my `<C-Tab>` and `<C-S-Tab>` with this:

```
if s:is_cygwin
    " <C-Tab> Next buffer
    set <f26>=[1;5I
    map <silent> <f26> :bn<cr>
    imap <silent> <f26> <c-o>:bn<cr>
    vmap <silent> <f26> <c-c>:bn<cr>

    " <C-S-Tab> Previous buffer
    set <f27>=[1;6I
    map <silent> <f27> :bp<cr>
    imap <silent> <f27> <c-o>:bp<cr>
    vmap <silent> <f27> <c-c>:bp<cr>
endif
```

I am wondering if there is a way do something similart for `<C-S-i>` or `<C-i>`?

Perhaps there is a fork of vim that supports any keyboard mapping or some options for mintty that allow to tweak the chars encoding.

My current solution is very ugly. I use AHK (AutoHotKeys) to remap  to another combination.

Does someone know any better workaround working on Windows/Mintty/Vim?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't generally possible today, even in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. (Unless your terminal sends a distinct *termcap* code for it, which most don't.) In insert or command-line mode, try typing the key combination. If nothing happens / is inserted, you cannot use that key combination. This also applies to `<Tab>` / `<C-I>`, `<CR>` / `<C-M>` / `<Esc>` / `<C-[>` etc. (Only exception is `<BS>` / `<C-H>`.) This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

Some people (foremost Paul LeoNerd Evans) want to fix that (even for console Vim in terminals that support this), and have floated various proposals, cp. http://groups.google.com/group/vim_dev/browse_thread/thread/626e83fa4588b32a/bfbcb22f37a8a1f8

But as of today, no patches or volunteers have yet come forward, though many have expressed a desire to have this in a future Vim 8 major release.

Comment: Have you heard about Neovim?

Comment: @coin: Yes. That one presumably removes this limitation, but is a work in progress. If it has all the features you need, switching would be a solution, too.